# Kunstmaan CMS: Form not getting passed to view

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm want to implement a Frontend form with KunstmaanCMS.

So i've created a Formpage and added a SingleLineTextPagePart to it. As described in the [docs](https://github.com/Kunstmaan/KunstmaanFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/FormBundle.md).

The backend is working, i can create the FormPagePart and it gets saved to the database properly.

When i load the frontendpage where the form should be displayed, i get the following exception:

```
Key "formwidget_KunstmaanFormBundleEntityPagePartsSingleLineTextPagePart1" in object with ArrayAccess of class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in KunstmaanFormBundle:SingleLineTextPagePart:view.html.twig at line 2
```

I guess i need to handle the form creation and submission somewhere. But i don't know how to achieve this.

I'm kind of stuck here. Any help is appreciated.